# xfce 4.10 package availability

Tags: package-management, ppa, xfce, deb

xfce 4.10 [has recently been released](http://xfce.org/about/news/?post=1335571200) but I cannot find a supported ppa available yet. There is this ppa https://launchpad.net/~xubuntu-dev/+archive/xfce-4.10 but it still remains empty.

Does anyone have any news on when/where an official ubuntu build will be released?

Comment: correct - its just been released.  Suggest contact the developers as to their release schedule.  This is really too localised to be answered here hence I'm closing the question.